# Recommendation for an advanced registry editor?

Tags: windows-registry

I am looking for advanced registry editor. So there are Chrome and Firefox in browsers area, notepad++ in text editing area, Photoshop in image editing area, Excel and Google Sheets for tables.

Therefore I am looking for this kind of 'one of the best or the best of the best' registry editor. I am interested in support of regular expressions, for example, so I can search for multiple things at the same time.

Any recommendations?

**Note**: I wouldn't auto search and replace all of the instances. I've been using that regedit for a decade now and it doesn't even have a '**find all instances in some specific area**' function, which is pretty lame.

Comment: I have to say that using an re search and replace in the registry would potentially be incredibly likely to leave you with an inoperable system.

Comment: I wouldn't auto search and replace all of the instances. I've been using that regedit for a decade now and it doesn't even have a **'find all instances in some specific area'** function, which is pretty lame.

Comment: Regedit is frankly awful I agree, _as is the registry in many ways,_ and the search speed leaves a lot to be desired but I still shudder at the mistakes that some people could or would make.